# Расскажите пожалуйста как рассчитать "stroke-dashoffset" и "stroke-dasharray" для SLD

Tags: geoserver

Хочу понять как правильно рассчитать "stroke-dasoffset" и "stroke-dasharray", что бы точки были на концах линии.
Возможно нужно указать два "stroke-dashoffset"?
Помогите,пожалуйста, получить такой результат.

[image: Помогите получить такой результат.]

На данный момент выходит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <sld:Rule>
      <sld:Name>Line1</sld:Name>
       <sld:LineSymbolizer>
        <sld:Stroke>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.5</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">45 25</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Stroke>
        <sld:PerpendicularOffset>-5</sld:PerpendicularOffset>
      </sld:LineSymbolizer>
      <sld:LineSymbolizer>
        <sld:Stroke>
          <sld:GraphicStroke>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#000000</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>5</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:GraphicStroke>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dashoffset">0</sld:CssParameter>
          <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">5 45</sld:CssParameter>
        </sld:Stroke>
        <PerpendicularOffset>-5</PerpendicularOffset>
      </sld:LineSymbolizer>
    </sld:Rule>
  </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Это расчет для точки посередине, но из этого можно пересчитать и на концы пунктиров

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]